Why does the Gemara say that Rabbi Zekharya's excessive humility caused the exile?
Gittin 55b states

Rabbi Yoḥanan says: The excessive humility of Rabbi Zekharya ben
Avkolas destroyed our Temple, burned our Sanctuary, and exiled us from
our land.

But that was already decreed to occur (due to sinas chinam), and so it seems it would've happened regardless of what Rabbi Zekharya ben Avkolas did or didn't do. What is the import of the Gemara's statement then?

If it's saying that the exile happened due to Rabbi Zekharya's choice (as a sort of punishment), that's difficult to accept because for one, he seemed to be acting in good faith and thought he was doing the right thing, also he did not foresee what the effect would be, and furthermore the scale and historic magnitude of the exile does not really fit as a punishment for having excessive humility.
And if it's simply stating that the exile was a consequence of Rabbi Zekharya's choice (in the sense of a natural chain of events proceeding from it), many different events contributed, so why is this one singled out?

Also, in general, if exile was already decreed to happen anyway, it can not really be said to have occurred due to a particular choice made by an individual. It seems like it would have happened no matter what Rabbi Zekharya would have chosen to do.

There's a third possibility. It could be that he had the ability to stop it (but didn't because of his humility etc). Hence the statement is hyperbole: "it happened because of him". Doesn't mean it was decreed because of him

I don't know if he had the ability to stop it, but he still contributed to it (similar to how, lehavdil, Titus was held responsible for carrying out the decreed destruction). It's singled out to teach a lesson about the hazard of misplaced humility.

I see many Talmudic assertions are educational rather than factual. I.e. it does not claim the fact that the destruction happened because of his humility, but rather warns that this type of behavior might lead to dangerous and destructive consequences.

They say that yes, the destruction was decreed already as you say. But it didn’t have to happen at that exact moment. Rabbi Zechariah “bumped it up” through his actions, because the churban was decreed but not when it would happen so he sped up the process

Another point, your question shouldn’t just be on Rabbi Zechariah. The Gemara earlier says that Jerusalem was destroyed because of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza. And then later it says the decree was sealed because of the incident of the master and apprentice. And other gemaras say the sin was not sinat chinam but rather Lashon Hara. Yet others say it was chillul Shabbat. So are all these contradictory? I don’t think so, I think they all contributed in their own way. But my point is you’re asking about Rabbi Zechariah but you can say this about any of the above

מגלגלין חוב על ידי חייב
